# Calling parent method from a modal or push view to presentingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

I have a `UINavigationGroup` with a root view controller called `MainViewController`. Inside this `MainViewController` I'm calling another `UINavigationController` as a modal as following:

```
- (IBAction)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController * someViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someNavigationController"];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:someViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Inside this `someNavigationController`, the user is going through some process so the nav controller is being pushed with some `UIViewControllers`. After the user completes the process, in the last `UIViewController` called `finalStepViewController`, I'm closing the modal as follow:

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

The modal is indeed dismissed and the user is back to the initial `MainViewController`.
However, I'd like to push another `UIViewController` to `MainViewController`'s NavigationController (for example: a view saying that the user completed the process successfully). Preferably before the modal is dismissed.

I have tried the following things:

**1. Using `presentingViewController`**

```
UIViewController * successViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"successViewController"];
[self.presentingViewController.navigationController successViewController animated:YES];
```

Result: no error, but nothing happening either.

**2. Delegate/protocol**

- Imported `finalStepViewController.h` inside `MainViewController.h` and appended `<finalStepViewControllerDelegate>`
- Inside `MainViewController.m` added a method called `parentMethodThatChildCanCall` to be called from `finalStepViewController.m`
- Added the following to `finalStepViewController.h`:

  `@protocol finalStepViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
  -(void)parentMethodThatChildCanCall;
  @end`
  `@property (assign) id <finalStepViewControllerDelegate> delegate;`
  and `@synthesize delegate;` in the model
- Set the delegate property to `someViewController` in the above mentioned `didTapButton` IBAction to self. This showed a notice error saying: `Assigning to id<UINavigationControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type UIViewController *const __strong'`
- Finally called `[self.delegate parentMethodThatChildCanCall]` just before closing the modal.

Result: except for the notice error, no fail but nothing happens as `parentMethodThatChildCanCall` is not called.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong/what I should be doing? It's my second week doing Objective-C, and most of the time I don't know what I'm doing so any help/code would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this a lot easier using `NSNotificationCenter`.

In your `MainViewController`'s `-viewDidLoad` add the following code

```
  typeof(self) __weak wself = self;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"successfullActionName"
                                                    object:nil
                                                     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  SuccessViewController *viewController; // instantiate it properly
                                                  [wself.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                                }];
```

Remove your controller from NSNotificationCenter upon dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

In `FinalStepViewController` on action that dismisses the view controller before dismiss post the notification

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"successfullActionName" object:nil];
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This example is very crude and is not ideal, you should use constants for your notification names and in some cases store the observers returned by `NSNotificationCenter` to remove specific ones.

-- EDIT
I'd like to also mention that the method `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` actually returns the observer as an `id` type object. You need to store a reference to it as an iVar in your class and remove it from the `NSNotificationCenter` when `dealloc` method is called otherwise that observer will never get deallocated.

Comment: This works, thanks for the quick answer. Can you elaborate/provide instructions on your last comment?

Comment: You should create static constants that have a self-explanatory name and use them instead of NSStrings for notificationName. As an example, in your case you might've created a constant `static NSString *const MYSuccessfullActionNotification = @"MYSuccessfullActionNotification";` and passed the constant value into `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MYSuccessfullActionNotification object:nil];`. Constants save you from typos basically.